# Commandline menu loop Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following problem:

I want to write a commandline-tool, where the user can input a command, and after its execution, the menu pops up again for the next command, until the user inserts `x`.

In Java, I would do it like this (or use a boolean in the Loop, set it and at the end, ask if it is true. However it is not a Java-question, this is just as example to show what I want):

```
loop1: do{
    printMenu();
    String input = readFromConsole();
    switch(input){
        case "a": //dostuff
            break;
        case "x": break loop1;
    }
}while (true);
```

Since there is no break in Scala, how should I do this?

One way that works is the following:

```
var cont = true
do{
    printMenu()
    val cmd = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    cmd match{
      case "c" => {
         //dostuff
      }
      case "x" => cont=false
      case _ => println("invalidCommand")

    }
}while(cont)
```

But since loops and mutable variables are not classic functional concepts, I guess there is a better, more Scala-like way.

Another way would be a recursive function, which calls itself everytime "x" is not inserted, but that also doesn't seem to be good style.

How should I do it (what is the best style)?
As mentioned, I already found a working solution, but it seems not really optimal. If it is, just let me know.

Sorry if this is a trivial question, but I searched around and didn't find much about this topic.

Comment: "a recursive function, which calls itself everytime "x" is not inserted, but that also doesn't seem to be good style." ==> That seems pretty good style to me to be honest ! Care to explain why you don't think so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an infinite iterator and then `takeWhile` the input isn't the exit command.

```
Iterator.continually(io.StdIn.readLine)
        .takeWhile(_ != "x")
        .foreach{
           case "this" => /* do this */
           case "that" => /* do that */
           case _      => /* default */
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tail recursion should be sufficient.

```
@tailrec
final def printMenu():Option[String] = {
  println("Put something: ")
  val cmd = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
  cmd match{
    case "c" => {
      return Some("Foo")
    }
    case "x" => return None
    case _ => printMenu()
  }
}

printMenu()
```